# Alter strings in a column based on duplicated data in other columns

Tags: r

I've got a dataset with yearly data that looks like this:

```
 year site_ID latitude longitude 
 2000   t2     61.5    -112.0667       
 2001   t2     61.5    -112.0667     
 2000   t3     21.2    -110.5
 2001   t3     21.2    -110.5
 2000   t4     61.5    -112.0667
 2001   t4     61.5    -112.0667
```

As you can see, sites `t2` and `t4` have the same coordinates. In cases such as these, I want to modify the `site_ID` to include the ID of the site that has the same latitude and longitude. So, something like this:

```
 year site_ID latitude longitude 
 2000   t2_t4     61.5    -112.0667       
 2001   t2_t4     61.5    -112.0667     
 2000   t3        21.2    -110.5
 2001   t3        21.2    -110.5
 2000   t2_t4     61.5    -112.0667
 2001   t2_t4     61.5    -112.0667
```

The names have to be identical (so `t2_t4` and NOT `t4_t2`) because later I will be aggregating such sites by the `site_ID`. Also, in some cases, there will be more than two duplicates. In these cases, I want to follow the same rule just with three ID's, e.g. `t2_t4_t5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use in `ave`, `unique` and `paste`:

```
x$site_ID <- ave(x$site_ID, x$latitude, x$longitude, FUN=function(y)
 paste(unique(y), collapse = "_"))
x
#  year site_ID latitude longitude
#1 2000   t2_t4     61.5 -112.0667
#2 2001   t2_t4     61.5 -112.0667
#3 2000      t3     21.2 -110.5000
#4 2001      t3     21.2 -110.5000
#5 2000   t2_t4     61.5 -112.0667
#6 2001   t2_t4     61.5 -112.0667
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="year site_ID latitude longitude 
 2000   t2     61.5    -112.0667       
 2001   t2     61.5    -112.0667     
 2000   t3     21.2    -110.5
 2001   t3     21.2    -110.5
 2000   t4     61.5    -112.0667
 2001   t4     61.5    -112.0667")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this grouping by variables and then using `mutate()` with `paste0()`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% group_by(year,latitude,longitude) %>%
  mutate(site_ID=paste0(site_ID,collapse = '_'))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   year, latitude, longitude [4]
   year site_ID latitude longitude
  <int> <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1  2000 t2_t4       61.5     -112.
2  2001 t2_t4       61.5     -112.
3  2000 t3          21.2     -110.
4  2001 t3          21.2     -110.
5  2000 t2_t4       61.5     -112.
6  2001 t2_t4       61.5     -112.
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, site_ID := paste(site_ID, collapse = "_"), .(year, latitude, longitude)]
```